TASK_WRITE_FAILED during csv write for Windows with PySpark
I have this python code that fails to write a dataframe to CSV:
output_dataframe.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").options(header="true",sep="\t").save("file:///D:/DataCleanupTests/Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-1/output.csv")

I get these errors:

24/07/06 20:34:09 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job
job_20240706203331247289827599787817_0003 aborted. 24/07/06 20:34:10
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 33.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 42)2]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: [TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while
writing rows to
file:/D:/DataCleanupTests/Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-1/output.csv.
Full trace too large to add here added to my Github for reference: https://github.com/russ960/DataCleanupTests/blob/main/TraceFileSaveFailure.txt

I have confirmed I have HADOOP_HOME pointing to the correct location in my installation.  I also have %HADOOP_HOME%\bin in my path.  I confirmed that %HADOOP_HOME%\bin points to the location of windtools.exe.  I have tried different variations on the path.  I've tried running as admin but the errors persist.

Can you give complete error traceback. I would start by writing a file at same path using a just python function, and then by changing permission to the directory 777 temporarily to check if it is related to access.

@palamuGuy I tried to put in no path and that didn't work.  Since this is windows 777 since I'm on Windows but I have tried opening VS Code as administrator with no change in the errors.

Can you try deleting exising files and directory or try writing to a new directory. In error traceback there is a warning message that says failed to delete file or dir. And after that your task fails. YOu can see that in line1, and line2 below:
24/07/06 20:34:10 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [D:\DataCleanupTests\Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-1\output.csv\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20240706203331247289827599787817_0003_m_000032_41\.part-00032-a723e743-6b08-46c5-8bef-58cdcbf6cfe4-c000.csv.crc]: it still exists. 
24/07/06 20:34:10 ERROR Utils: Aborting task org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException

You can clean the output directory programatically before writing to it, or you can programmatically write to different directories based on timestamp.
output_path = "D:/DataCleanupTests/Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-1/output.csv"

# Clean up the output directory if it exists
if os.path.exists(output_path):
    shutil.rmtree(output_path)

 try:
        df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").options(header="true", sep="\t").save(output_path)
        print("Data written successfully.")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"failed: {e}")



I tried this with no success.  I did find the issue while I had winutils I was missing hadoop.dll which was missing from a blog I was following.  Once added it worked.
